# Summing numbers in a single cell - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, cell

Cell E5 contains 5v5+4. I want cell F5 to sum the numbers in cell E5, to give 14.

How can I do that?

I have no idea how to do that, so didn't try anything.

For context, I this is for a football drill project where I need both the total number of players and the breakdown of players in each team.

Comment: You should always keep single data in single cells. And then visualize them according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `TEXTSPLIT()` function:

[image]

---

```
=SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(F5,"+",CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,97)),,,0))
```

---

Or,

```
=SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(F5,"+",CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)+{0,32}),,,0))
```

---

The second approach ensures to exclude any alphabets whether small or caps, along with `+` operator to return an array of numbers as text, therefore on adding a `double unary` converts numbers returned as text to actual number for math operation. For converting the same, using `+0` or `/1` or `*1` can also be used.

---

Or as mentioned by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, using nested `TEXTSPLIT()`

```
=SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(E5,TEXTSPLIT(E5,ROW(1:10)-1,,1)))
```

---

Comment: Or, `=SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(E5,TEXTSPLIT(E5,ROW(1:10)-1,,1)))`

Comment: Oh wow, double `TEXTSPLIT()`